# Is it possible to have same URI with different headers in REST?

Tags: java, json, rest

I was trying to register two resources with same URI and different headers. Say for,

`-X www.xyz.com/customerid/123/ -H 'Accept: application/json profile="customer.1.json"' -D 'abc.json'`

`-X www.xyz.com/customerid/123/ -H 'Accept: application/json profile="customer.2.json"' -D 'abcd.json'`

when I tried to do it I was getting this error

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
>   [[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Is there any other way to overcome this issue with a workaround?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding headers, only [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) and [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) are taken into account for the request matching process. Other headers (including any arbitrary headers) are irrelevant.

---

The JAX-RS runtime uses the following for matching requests to resource methods:

- **URI:** Defined in the [`@Path`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation.
- **Request method:** Defined by a resource method designator such as [`@GET`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/GET.html), [`@POST`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/POST.html), etc).
- **Media type:** Defined in [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) and [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) headers, that are matched with the values defined in the [`@Produces`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) and [`@Consumes`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) annotations, respectively.

For further details, check the [JSR 370](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_1-final-eval-spec/jaxrs-2_1-final-spec.pdf).

---

Depending on your needs, you could define a *custom media type*. Have a look at the GitHub API v3 [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/media/) for some insights.